# loading schema problem

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have the following schema.yml:

```
Category:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: category
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    url_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SCategory:
      local: id
      foreign: category_id
      type: many
SCategory:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: s_category
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    category_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    url_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Category:
      local: category_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    SsCategory:
      local: id
      foreign: s_category_id
      type: many
SsCategory:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: ss_category
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    s_category_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    url_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SCategory:
      local: s_category_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

when I try to load the following data:

```
Category:
   TV_HiFi_video:
      name:TV, HiFi & vidéo
SCategory:
   Elements_separes_Hi_Fi:
       name:Eléments séparés Hi Fi
       category_id:TV_HiFi_video
SsCategory:
   Amplificateur:
       name:Amplificateur
       s_category_id:Elements_separes_Hi_Fi
```

it says "data was succesfully loaded" but no data is added in the db.
cheers

Comment: How did you check? Did you run `./symfony doctrine:dql "FROM Category"`, for instance?

Comment: how did i check what? btw i ran the normal queries you run when initiating a project

Comment: What command are you using to load the data? How are you checking the data? I'm guessing you're using `doctrine:data-load` -- what happens if you add the `-t` flag? Do you get any better info?

Comment: this is what i get with -t :    http://i.imgur.com/tvNmw.jpg

Comment: are you missing spaces after the column names in your YAML fixture?

Comment: @tada: how did you check [whether your data was loaded or not, of course]?

Comment: I check by looking at phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay, that looks odd. You should see INSERT statements in the trace for every row inserted. Where exactly *is* your fixtures file? What happens if you pass it as a parameter to the data-load, e.g. `symfony doctrine:data-load -t data/fixtures/the-fixtures-file.yml`?

Comment: Also, I notice many of your fixtures have non-ASCII characters -- this is fine, but do double-check the encoding of your fixtures file; make sure it's saved as UTF-8.

Comment: @yitznewton I agree that there should be a space after each colon in the column values in the fixtures file (@tada, this means `category_id:TV_HiFi_video` should be `category_id: TV_HiFi_video`, for example, and the other entries should have that extra space, too.) However, that should produce a clear syntax error message rather than just nothing happening, so I think there's also something else going on.

Comment: thank you, yes missing spaces after the column name killed the correct yml parsing.So now(yes with other structural problems) everything should be fine, thank you guys.

Comment: @tada: you should use yaml editor with syntax validation. If you're using eclipse PDT, then have a look at the yedit editor, it shows you errors like this one.

Comment: thanks, im really starting to think that i hate symfony.

Comment: @tada: Oh really? Have you found a better php framework? But here the problem is with Doctrine, not symfony, and though like Doctrine, I must say it sometimes is far too silent.